# WCHAR* array only ever has one item in it when passed

Tags: c++, arrays, directx

I'm trying to pass an array of `WCHAR` to my terrain shader, however when I am debugging I can only ever see one item in the array even though I specify 2 objects when I call the code.

The receiving function looks like:

```
bool TerrainLoader::Init(ID3D11Device* device, char* heightmap, WCHAR* textures[]) {}
```

I put a breakpoint when the method is called and can only find one element in the inspector, however the call to this func looks like this:

```
// Build an array of textures to pass to the terrain renderer
WCHAR* textures[2];
textures[0] = L"./textures/dirt01.dds";
textures[1] = L"./textures/seafloor.dds";
success = m_worldTerrain->Init(m_D3D->GetDevice(), "./levels/test.bmp", textures);
```

As seen above, there are two elements in the array, why am I only seeing one on the other side (still a bit of a c++ noobie!)

Comment: You can't pass arrays to functions in C or C++, only pointers to their first element. (Which you can then use to access all the elements, *but the debugger doesn't know that*)

Comment: Hmm, I'm lost...so there isn't a way to solve this without expanding my function prototype?

Comment: Your code is probably fine. It's the debugger that is not displaying it the way you want.